# Feature matching with flann in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, feature-extraction, flann

I am working on an image search project for which i have defined/extracted the key point features using my own algorithm. Initially i extracted only single feature and tried to match using cv2.FlannBasedMatcher() and it worked fine which i have implemented as below:

```
Here vec is 2-d list of float values of shape (10, )
Ex:
[[0.80000000000000004, 0.69999999999999996, 0.59999999999999998, 0.44444444444444448, 0.25, 0.0, 0.5, 2.0, 0, 2.9999999999999996]

[2.25, 2.666666666666667, 3.4999999999999996, 0, 2.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.37499999999999994, 0.20000000000000001, 0.10000000000000001]

[2.25, 2.666666666666667, 3.4999999999999996, 0, 2.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.37499999999999994, 0.20000000000000001, 0.10000000000000001]

[2.25, 2.666666666666667, 3.4999999999999996, 0, 2.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.37499999999999994, 0.20000000000000001, 0.10000000000000001]]

vec1 = extractFeature(img1)
vec2 = extractFeature(img2)

q1 = np.asarray(vec1, dtype=np.float32)
q2 = np.asarray(vec2, dtype=np.float32)

FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)   # or pass empty dictionary
flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params,search_params)
matches = flann.knnMatch(q1,q2,k=2)
```

But now i have one more feature descriptor for each key point along with previous one but of different length.
So now my feature descriptor has shape like this:

```
[[[0.80000000000000004, 0.69999999999999996, 0.59999999999999998, 0.44444444444444448, 0.25, 0.0, 0.5, 2.0, 0, 2.9999999999999996],[2.06471330e-01,   1.59191645e-02,   9.17678759e-05, 1.32570314e-05,   4.58424252e-10,   1.66717250e-06,6.04810165e-11]

[[2.25, 2.666666666666667, 3.4999999999999996, 0, 2.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.37499999999999994, 0.20000000000000001, 0.10000000000000001],[ 2.06471330e-01,   1.59191645e-02,   9.17678759e-05, 1.32570314e-05,   4.58424252e-10,   1.66717250e-06, 6.04810165e-11],

[[2.25, 2.666666666666667, 3.4999999999999996, 0, 2.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.37499999999999994, 0.20000000000000001, 0.10000000000000001],[ 2.06471330e-01,   1.59191645e-02,   9.17678759e-05, 1.32570314e-05,   4.58424252e-10,   1.66717250e-06, 6.04810165e-11],

[[2.25, 2.666666666666667, 3.4999999999999996, 0, 2.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.37499999999999994, 0.20000000000000001, 0.10000000000000001],[ 2.06471330e-01,   1.59191645e-02,   9.17678759e-05, 1.32570314e-05,  4.58424252e-10,   1.66717250e-06, 6.04810165e-11]]
```

Now since each point's feature descriptor is a list two lists(descriptors) with different length that is (10, 7, ) so in this case i am getting error:

> setting an array element with a sequence.

while converting feature descriptor to numpy array of float datatype:

```
q1 = np.asarray(vec1, dtype=np.float32)
```

I understand the reason of this error is different length of lists, so i wonder What would be the right way to implement the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should define a single descriptor of size `10+7=17`.

This way, the space descriptor is now of 17 and you should be able to use `cv2.FlannBasedMatcher`.

Either create a global descriptor of the correct size `desc_glob = np.zeros((nb_pts,17))` and fill it manually or find a Python way to do it. Maybe `np.reshape((nb_pts,17))`?

**Edit:**

To not favor one descriptor type over the other, you need to weight or normalize the descriptors. This is the same principle than computing a global descriptor distance from two descriptors:

> dist(desc1, desc2) = dist(desc1a, desc2a) + lambda * dist(desc1b, desc2b)

Comment: would this be valid even if two features have different dimensions?

Comment: No, the descriptor size for all features has to be the same. Otherwise, you cannot compute the distance between them. This is like computing the distance between a 2D point and a 3D point. This is not valid unless you convert the 2D point to a 3D point and assign the z-coordinate with a default value, e.g. 0.

Comment: sorry for the typo, i was asking for the case of vectors with different units or types, say vec1 is representing radius feature at a point and vec2 is representing area feature at key point. Do i have to assign certain weights to the vectors in order to normalize them?

Comment: Yes, you probably need to normalize or weight the descriptor in order to not favor one descriptor type against the other. It is the same thing than with two descriptors, you have to find a way to compute a global distance: `dist(desc1a, desc2a) + lambda * dist(desc1b, desc2b)`.